# SSIS imports data differently between machines

Tags: visual-studio-2008, csv, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, etl

I am using VS 2008 to create an SSIS package and I am finding the same package is importing data differently when the package is moved to a different machine.

In my SSIS package I have a script task which is first to run, and it runs fine.  The next step is to take CSV files (created in the script task) and import them into the database.  To test this I do the following in VS:

Build my solution
Build my SSIS package
Run the SSIS package from VS

All of this works fine.  So I then go to my bin folder where the DTSX file is and I then create a SQL job out of that package.

When I run this package I notice it is failing and when I dig deeper, it is failing because the data being imported from the CSV files has the quotes imported into the table as well, like this:

```
PolicyNumber    FamilyMemberID  LastName
"000001"            "A"         "Wilkinson"
"000001"            "Z"         "Wilkinson"
"000002"            "R"         "Trujillo"
```

It should look like this:

```
PolicyNumber    FamilyMemberID  LastName
000001              A           Wilkinson
000001              Z           Wilkinson
000002              R           Trujillo
```

I am confused because I am running the same package against the same files but it is just being executed on two different machines and I don't think something like this could be an issue of rights.

Also, my settings for the CSV file are to use a quote as a text qualifier

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWFKu.jpg

Comment: Are the quotes in the CSV file?  Can you post a screenshot of the CSV file?

Comment: Yes, there are quotes in the CSV file because some of the columns have a comma, so I had to add the quotes.

Here is part of the file (it has sensitive data so I can't show it all) - http://imgur.com/FsUUqZb  But every column has quotes EXCEPT the column headers.  Could that be my problem?

Comment: And it works they way you want it on another machine?

Comment: Yes, it works fine on the development machine.  Which is why I am now testing it in SQL Server

Comment: Try using Derived Column transformations.

Comment: One more thing to add...this same package was failing on the server a few days ago because the Office drivers weren't installed (I write results to an Excel file).  That has been resolved but I now have this new issue.  So something did change on the server (which is where this won't run properly) but I don't know how this could be the result since the setting is correct.

Comment: how do you import into the db, is it via flat file source to OLE DB destination in SSIS, or BULK INSERT in sql script?  Are the two runs importing into the same SQL Server instance ?

Comment: I import using OLE DB Command because I use A stored procedure.  You can use OLE DB Destination if you want.  My suggestions is to avoid as much manual scripting as possible and use the objects that SSIS provides.

Comment: are you familiar with stored procedures?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your Flat File Source, click Show Advance Editor, click Input and Output Properties, expand Flat File Source Output, expand External Columns, click on each of the columns showing and change the DataType property
 to Unicode_String for each column, and then do the same for Output Columns.  See if this helps.

Following the above process and keeping " (quotes) as your text qualifier, you are going to have to use 2 Derived column transformations and have your Data Flow look like the following screen shot:

[image]

In the first Derived Column transformation, input what you see in the screen shot as follows:

[image]

In the second Derived Column transformation, input what you see in the screen shot as follows:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Note:  I used the Excel Destination for testing, per your solution you will want to use either an OLE DB Destination object or OLE DB Command object.